# Yii2 Model Rules are not Firing on Post

Tags: yii2, rules

I have quite a simple form using Yii2 but for some reason my model rules are nor firing when I hit the submit button. Below is my UI form.

```
<?php
$form = ActiveForm::begin(['id' => 'paperadduserform',])
?>
      <?= $form->field($registerModel, 'userFirstname')->textInput(
        [placeholder' => 'Enter first name',
        class'=>'form-control form-control-sm border-primary',
        maxlength'=>'40'])->label(false); ?>

      <?= $form->field($registerModel, 'userLastname')->textInput(
        [placeholder' => 'Enter last name',
        class'=>'form-control form-control-sm border-primary',
        maxlength'=>'40'])->label(false); ?>

      <?= Html::submitButton('Add Reviewer', ['id'=>'registerBtn','class' => 'btn btn-primary btn-xl']) ?>

<?php ActiveForm::end() ?>
```

This is my Model class which contains the Rules.

```
class PaperAddUserForm extends Model
{
    public $userFirstname;
    public $userLastname;

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            ['userFirstname', 'trim'],
            ['userFirstname', 'required'],
            ['userFirstname', 'string', 'min' => 1, 'max' => 40],

            ['userLastname', 'trim'],
            ['userLastname', 'required'],
            ['userLastname', 'string', 'min' => 1, 'max' => 40],
        ];
    }


    private function addUser($role)
    {
        try {
            $user = new User();
            $user->user_firstname = $this->userFirstname;
            $user->user_lastname = $this->userLastname;
            $user->save(false);

            $auth = \Yii::$app->authManager;
            $authorRole = $auth->getRole($role);
            $auth->assign($authorRole, $user->getId());

        } catch (Exception $e) {
            throw $e;
        }
    }


    public function paperAddReviewer()
    {
        $this->addUser(AuthRolesEnum::OC_REVIEWER);
        return true;
    }
}
```

This is part of my Controller class.

```
public function actionAddReviewer()
{
    $registerModel = new PaperAddUserForm();

    if ($registerModel->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $registerModel->paperAddReviewer()) {
        return $this->redirect(['/paper/reviewer/reviewer']);
    }

    return $this->render('/paper/reviewer/add-reviewer',
        [
            'registerModel' => $registerModel,
        ]);
}
```

But when I run the application, the fields are not marked as required when I leave them empty. When I hit the submit button it tries to save to the DB, it does not give me the 'Field is Required' error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not calling [`yii\base\Model::validate()`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-base-model#validate()-detail) method anywhere. The rules are not applied if you just define them. The definition is used when validation is triggered.

If your model extends `yii\db\ActiveRecord` then the `validate()` method is called during its `save()` method unless you've passed `false` in its `$runValidation` parameter.

But in case your model extends `yii\base\Model` directly, you have to call the `validate()` method explicitly.

In your case you can add the `validate()` call in your controller like this:

```php
if (
    $registerModel->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) 
    && $registerModel->validate()
    && $registerModel->paperAddReviewer()
) {
    return $this->redirect(['/paper/reviewer/reviewer']);
}
```

Or you can make it part of your `PaperAddUserForm::paperAddReviewer()` method like this:

```php
public function paperAddReviewer()
{
    if (!$this->validate()) {
        return false;
    }
    $this->addUser(AuthRolesEnum::OC_REVIEWER);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: OH MY WORD...how did I miss that :) You are absolutely right. Thank You